# #Gulp# How to output files to the path which depends on the path of input files?

Tags: gulp

Say I have these folders:

```
./
|
folder1/
  |---file1.js
  |---file2.js
folder2/
  |---file1.js
  |---file2.js
```

I want to run a task with gulp.src('./**/*.js'), and I want them to be output as the following:

```
./
|
folder1/
  |---file1.js
  |---file2.js
  |---file1.min.js
  |---file2.min.js
folder2/
  |---file1.js
  |---file2.js
  |---file1.min.js
  |---file2.min.js
```

Comment: What have you tried already?  Have you tried reading the manual or searching the internet yet?

Comment: @OverZealous Yep I've searched internet but found nothing. I've read this article:　https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.md . But this need to do something with the gulp file, adding some functions and etc.( and I don't want to run task steps per folder) Maybe I should write my own dist function to output files?

Answer (score 2):

This really is something that you can solve by reading any one of a number of gulp articles already out there.  [Google for *gulp tutorial*](https://www.google.com/#q=gulp+tutorial) and start reading articles.

By default, the relative source path for an input file is preserved through to the output file in gulp.  You don't have to do anything special.  If you want something similar to what you've got, you need to use a JS minifier, such as [the `gulp-uglify` plugin](https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-uglify), and [the `gulp-rename` plugin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-rename).

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({extname: '.min.js'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'));
});
```

The relative path is based on the first glob in the string, in the example above, it's the `**`, so the relative path would be any folders after `src/`.  This means a file at `src/foo/bar.js` would be saved as `dest/foo/bar.min.js`, because the relative path is `foo/`.